How to define action if the actions are state-dependent and the action space are huge?
I'm trying to use RL to solve my problem. This problem has a huge state space (discrete) and a huge action space. Also, the actions available for each state are varied (depending on the state). Hence, I can't use the generic DQN where the output states equal the number of classes. Also, I have problems encoding the actions into the NN (because of the size and different categories). However, the transition in this problem is deterministic, in which I know the next state from the current state after taking an action.
Are there any ways to represent the actions? Or is there a better RL algorithm than DQN I can use?
Thanks
The current thought is to train a DQN where the input is both the current state and the next state after taking an action.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
